# How to get total instance from two jquery:contains() selector instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, contains

I need help on how to get total instance from 2 jquery:contains() selector instances. For some multiple requirements, I need to get two instances of the variables and show total results without duplication.

To explain further, here are the details -

The html div block -

```
<div id="results"></div>

<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Global, City1</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Global City1</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Global, City2</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Global City2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Global, City3</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Global City3</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Global, City4</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Global City4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Main1, City1</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Main1 City1</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="keywords" style="display:none">Main2, City2</div>
<div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Main2 City2</div>
</div>
```

My javascript -

```
    var keyword= "Global";
var keyword2= "Main";

$('.container').has('.keywords:contains('+keyword+')').children(".display").show();

var text = "";
var i = 0;

while (i < keyword.length) {
        text += ":contains('"+keyword[i]+"')";
        i++;
    }

// keyword 2
$('.container').has('.keywords:contains('+keyword2+')').children(".display").show();

var text2 = "";
var x = 0;

while (x < keyword2.length) {
        text2 += ":contains('"+keyword2[i]+"')";
        x++;
    }

var results1 = $("div[class^=keywords]"+text+"").length;
var results2 = $("div[class^=keywords2]"+text2+"").length;
var results = results1 + results2;

$("#results").append(results);
```

My test cases -

1. If var keyword = = "Global" and var keyword2= "Global"; then 4 results, because Global and Global have 4 matched instances. - OK
2. If var keyword = = "Global" and var keyword2= "Main"; then it still shows 4 results, but it should be 6 results because there are 6 matched instances. - Not Correct

Here's my fiddle for reference - http://jsfiddle.net/358bx237/

How can I correct my code to show 6 results for test case #2?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok. Since the answer is not working. I would delete the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your while loop iterates over `keyword` - not an array of keywords as you intend:
You do this:

```
var keyword= "Global";

while (i < keyword.length) {
        text += ":contains('"+keyword[i]+"')";
        i++;
}
```

You basically iterate over all the letters of your first keyword - which ends up selecting this: `$("div[class^=keywords]:contains('G'):contains('l'):contains('o'):contains('b'):contains('a'):contains('l')`

What you should be doing is create an array that holds your keywords and iterate over that (and make sure you do an OR selection)

http://jsfiddle.net/358bx237/5/
    var keywordArray = [keyword, keyword2];
    var text = "";
    var i = 0;
    var first = true;
    while (i < keywordArray.length) { //change here - keyword is not an array 
        if (!first) text += ",";
        first = false;

```
    text += "div[class^=keywords]:contains('" + keywordArray[i] + "')"
    //  text += ":contains('"+keywordArray[i]+"')";
    i++;
}
console.log(text);
var results = $(text).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
function keyFilters(keys) {
  var $els = $('.container .keywords'),
    $result = $();
  $.each(keys, function(i, key) {
    $result = $result.add($els.filter(':contains(' + key + ')'));
  });
  return $result;
}

function test(keys) {
  $('#results').append('<div>Keys: ' + keys.join(', ') + ': ' + keyFilters(keys).length + '</div>')
}

test(['Global', 'Global']);
test(['Main', 'Global']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="keywords" style="display:none">Global, City1</div>
  <div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Global City1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="keywords" style="display:none">Global, City2</div>
  <div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Global City2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="keywords" style="display:none">Global, City3</div>
  <div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Global City3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="keywords" style="display:none">Global, City4</div>
  <div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Global City4</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="keywords" style="display:none">Main1, City1</div>
  <div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Main1 City1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="keywords" style="display:none">Main2, City2</div>
  <div class="display" style="display:none">Results one for Main2 City2</div>
</div>
```